# Making new tables based on time gaps

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm using an MS 2010 access database table that is populated by records from a gps. The time field increments sequentially by one second, except in certain sections where the machine has been turned off, creating a time gap of more than one second. So:

```
Time
---------
12:00:00
12:00:01
12:00:02
....
12:01:00
12:01:01
12:04:03
12:04:04
....
etc.
```

The time doesn't always start precisely at 12:00:00, this is just an example. There will be many such gaps, also. What I would like to do is make new tables for each of the 'runs' of sequential records. Can this be accomplished with SQL alone or do I need to do it in a VBA environment?

Comment: you shouldn't do that.  it sounds like something that you would want to use reporting software for.  store it all in the same table, but query around the gaps. maybe give the table an indicator of the sessions.  `on` and `off`

Comment: Anything else in the table that needs to be preserved, or is it just the times?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new table, you should create a field with an index that increments each time the jump is made out-of-sequence.  You can then query based on the time fields, and use the indexes to treat each sequence of the data separately.